# Fast way in Matlab to compute inverse of big matrix 10800x10800?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix of size 10800x10800 in Matlab and I compute its inverse
directly with the function:

```
inv(A)
```

It takes 3 to 4 minutes just one such computation. And that is part of an
iterative algorithm which needs more than 20 iterations, so overall things would
be very slow. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe some mathematical formulas
or maybe a better Matlab function?

Edit: The matrix is diagonal. Each iteration the diagonal elements are updated
based on formulas for fitting a factor analyzer. But that is irrelevant, the
important thing is that it is a diagonal matrix and it changes each iteration.

THanks

Comment: Usually, taking an explicit `inv()` can be avoided, but we need to see more code to understand that.

Comment: what changes at each iteration? there are incremental formulas for inverse matrices for all sorts of things. It really depends on the particular manipulations you do at each iteration

Comment: I have edited my original post and provided more info.

Comment: if your matrix is diagonal it is EXTREMELY sparse!

Comment: yes it is sorry, I was thinking of other stuff. By the way, 3lectrologos answered my question below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your matrix is indeed diagonal, you can obviously just do

```
Ainv = diag(1./diag(A));
```

which should be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash operator `\` is said to be [faster](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/how-does-the-matlab-backslash-operator-solve-ax-b-for-square-matrices) and also could be more accurate. Without MATLAB really I cannot tell, but you could try to run `A \ eye(10800)` instead of `inv(A)`, and see if it works out.